# removing osx preview temp files

Tags: macos, preview.app

When I open a PDF file from email / webpage, preview automatically opens it up for me. But it saves a temp copy of the file on Desktop and it clusters up after a while. Is there a way to change the temp file directory for preview / automatically remove those temporaries after closing them?

Answer (score 0):

If you're content to leave the PDF just in the email itself, what about using Quick Look instead?

Just select the file to view, tap the spacebar, same again to hide it.

For a PDF on a web page, one solution would be to just open it in Safari, then it will just recycle with the cache. To open it with Preview requires it to be downloaded locally, so you'd need to set Safari's prefs > General > Save downloaded files to... somewhere more convenient.
As a download, it would not be considered a temporary file, so will not delete automatically.